# Will QR code be able to be implemented in this scenario?

Tags: web-apps, software-development, web-development, web, qr-code

User registers on the website. Upon registration, the system will generate a QR code for the user. The user then goes to be vaccinated, and upon vaccination, someone will be able to scan his/ her QR code and the status of the user will be updated as vaccinated with the 1st dose of the vaccine. Additional information will also include, the date for the 2nd dose of vaccination, the doctor who was responsible for the vaccination, date and time of the vaccination. The user can also give his feedback for the side effects per dosage.

Most tutorials with QR code scanners are in a mobile application. However, my laptop might not be capable of handling mobile development.

1. Will the QR code in this scenario be able to be implemented?
2. What are some packages for this QR code generator and scanner?
3. If I'll use reactjs, are there still any npm packages for QR codes? From what I've researched, some of them were not maintained anymore. Other recommended technologies are open as well.
4. If perhaps, we could develop the user in a mobile application, would it be more difficult developing in a mobile application or web application? Considering that, I've never developed a mobile application. But there are tons of tutorials on YouTube. For a web application, I've already developed an online food ordering. However, there were not many tutorials on how to implement the QR code in a web app. The time frame for our project would be only around 3-4 months and also, this QR code scanning and generator will only be a feature. There are still other modules as well.

Comment: if you want to scan QR codes with a computer you might want to consider buying a handheld barcode scanner capable of reading QR codes. these scanners will act like a keyboard and simply write the contents of the scanned code.

Comment: Are you looking for a commercial product or something available at no cost?

Comment: @totalynotanoob  I want to use a generated QR code within the website so it'll be accessed with a browser.

Comment: @BenThompson i was wondering if I could implement a QR code generator and scanner in a website.

Answer (score 1):

It's feasible to incorporate a generator and scanner into a site using HTML5 and javascript.  If you're interested in using a commercial product, the LEADTOOLS SDK may be sufficient.  Here's how a barcode can be scanned using HTML5/JS.
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/javascript/dox/documentbarcodes.html

Note for generating barcodes with this toolkit a back-end service will be necessary.  This can be in .NET as well.
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/ba/barcodewriter.html

Note implementation difficulty in different platforms would be subjective.  You can also leverage the Xamarin framework (note Microsoft is in the process of replacing this framework) to create a single cross-platform code base for deployment to different mobile devices.  When using the LEADTOOLS SDK one other option to consider is a web application requiring the user to visit a site would require a server and back-end framework, while with a mobile app the recognition would take place on the device itself and not require an internet connection.

You can download the evaluation SDK from [the official site](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).  Disclaimer:  I work for the company which manufactures this product.